# How can I convert string to JSON in Model class

Tags: javascript, json, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like convert string to JSON while receiving the value from API. I am sending value from postman but I am unable to convert it to the JSON object in the model class ,I have decorated model class with the custom decorator. Thanks in Advance.

This is the Model Class and I wrote custom JSON convertor.

```
 namespace WebApplication2.Models
   {
    [Serializable]
    public class Test
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(UserConverter))]
        public AS_AscContext AscParcelContext { get; set; }

    }
    public class AS_AscContext
    {
        public string ShellType { get; set; }
        public string LayoutName { get; set; }
    }

   
    public class UserConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        private readonly Type[] _types;

        public UserConverter(params Type[] types)
        {
            _types = types;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

            if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            {
                t.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                JObject o = (JObject)t;
                IList<string> propertyNames = o.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

                o.AddFirst(new JProperty("Keys", new JArray(propertyNames)));

                o.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
        }
    }
```

**This is the controller receiving value**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Privacy([FromBody]Test aS_AggregatorRequest)
    {
       
        return View();
    }
```

[This is the postman collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg6fY.png)

Comment: The JSON you included in the "postman collection" photo does not look like valid JSON. Are you sure that's what you need to parse?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Yes I need to parse above mentioned JSON string to JSON object

Comment: I understood that from the question, but I was curious about how you want to approach this, as the thing you included in the photo is invalid (cannot be parsed to JSON in its actual form). How do you intend to fix it? For example, there's a comma at the very end. That should not exist there. After you remove the comma, you have a valid JSON object that has a property called "ascParcelContext" of type string. That is something you can parse into a JSON.

Comment: From the content of the question, and the structure of your models, I understand that you also want to parse the content of the "ascParcelContext" property to a JSON object, but that again is invalid. "ShellType" is a valid property name, and "ceme-sales-wallaby" also seems to be a valid string value for that ShellType property, but then you have the "LayoutName" property with no value, which is invalid.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I made correction still its not working

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly "not working" means? Can you include the error that you get? You know you should implement the ReadJson method, right? The WriteJson is used to convert your object into a JSON string. I believe you need the reverse of that, which is convert a string into an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your postman JSON like this,

```
   {
      "ascParcelContext": {
          "shellType": "ceme-sales-wallaby",
          "layoutName": "value"
     }
   }
```

Don't escape any of the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

your json has another json inside. So it is better to fix the api but if you don't have an access try this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Privacy([FromBody]JObject jsonObject)
{

jsonObject["ascParcelContext"]= JObject.Parse( (string) jsonObject["ascParcelContext"]);

Test test = jsonObject.ToObject<Test>();

.....

}

public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("ascParcelContext")]
    public AS_AscContext AscParcelContext { get; set; }

}
public class AS_AscContext
{
    [JsonProperty("shellType")]
    public string ShellType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("layoutName")]
    public string LayoutName { get; set; }
}
```